# How to set value in selected columns?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I use this code for select columns

```
select cities.name,cities.geom,cities.area
from cities,delivery
where ST_Intersects(delivery.geom,cities.geom)
```

It return this result

[image: It return this result]
How i can set value "true" for "area" column?
I am not familiar with the language - tell me how to set the values? Biggest thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update cities set area = 'true'
from delivery
where ST_Intersects(delivery.geom,cities.geom);
```